# Saving Dataset to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

I am trying to save a dataset to a database.  I got a dataset from another class, Now changes will be made on the form by a user on a datagridview, then the changed Dataset needs to be saved in the database.

I am using the below code; Its not generating any errors, but the data is not being saved in the database.

```
public class myForm    
{    
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    public void PouplateGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlService sql = new SqlService(connectionString); // Valid Connection String, No Errors


            myDataSet = sql.ExecuteSqlDataSet("SELECT * FROM Qualification"); // Returns a DataSet
            myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            myDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            myDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error");
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //myDataSet.AcceptChanges();EDIT:Don't know why, but this line wasn't letting the chane in db happen.
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Qualification", sql.Connection); //ADDED after Replies
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da); //ADDED after replies
        da.Update(myDataSet.Tables[0]);
    }
}
public class mySqlService
{
public DataSet ExecuteSqlDataSet(string sql)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            this.Connect();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            cmd.CommandTimeout = this.CommandTimeout;
            cmd.Connection = _connection;
            if (_transaction != null) cmd.Transaction = _transaction;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(ds);
            da.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();

            if (this.AutoCloseConnection) this.Disconnect();

            return ds;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? There are ways on the web to save the dataset, if the datset is created, edited and saved in the same class etc., BUT I would like to have the select dataset method in the mySqlService class. How should I, now can save the dataset to the database?

EDIT:
I have commented the three lines that were required to make the code work. The code works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run *Update* method of `SqlDataAdapter` you must have to configure `InsertCommand`, `DeleteCommand` and `UpdateCommand` properties along with `SelectCommand` of SqlDataAdapter or construct the [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) object which configure these commands implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Hey try following this tutorial here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308507 first and then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, :) The article explains in detail what AVD answered. :)