# inserting xls file values into the odbc database

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to insert my xls file sheet into the ODBC server in c# .....kindly help me out with its c#   coding....I can only find sql server related problems in the internet as i want to  work in ODBC.
this is my coding :-

```
    string ConnectionString, str;

    OdbcConnection con;

    OdbcCommand cmd;

    SqlBulkCopy bkcp ;

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=ak_db.excel_table;Uid=root;Pwd=root";

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(ConnectionString))
        {

            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", con);

            con.Open();

            // Create OdbcDataReader to Data Worksheet

            using (OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                // SQL Server Connection String

                string OdbcConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=ak_db.excel_table;Uid=root;Pwd=root";

         }
```

i dont know what to do after this ...so kindly  help me out....

Comment: @Siddharth Rout:- cn u help me out here sir..??

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is to read the values from your excel file and store them in a dataset like described here:

[Reading-Excel-Files-From-C-Sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp)

and then writing this dataset to your online database:

[saving-dataset-to-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608546/saving-dataset-to-database)

Good Luck!

Comment: itz same as above...,..actually m nt able to append the code from the link into my code.....

Comment: Well I'm not gonna write the code for you, I am willing to point you in the right direction. Try the following to start.. You have a connectionstring and your oledb command, so far so good, now create a dataset and fill it up, you can follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx you should be able to do this now.