# save changes in a dataset to a table in a database

Tags: c#, dataset

I need some help showing me how to go about storing/saving changes made in a dataset back to the table(s) in the database.
I'm using C# with windows forms on visual studio. Database is a local SQL Server.

I have managed to get the data to the data set but cannot save changes.
the below is not saving to the database.
ds is my dataset.

```
ds.AcceptChanges();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
dataAdaptor.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Dataset to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608546/saving-dataset-to-database) and several dozen other existing questions. Please make at least a basic effort to search for existing questions before posting a new one here.

Comment: Thanks Ken, and everyone who answered, I have actually been searching for weeks on this site and all over the internet, but I can't seem to get my hand on the write leads, maybe there is a significant gap in my understanding somewhere... So I thought to ask the question generally, maybe the question was not clear enough. I was looking for a theoretical answer not necessarily a piece of code, I have read on msdn about all types of datasets and their adapters, but still cannot get anything to work in my case. I do realise it's a very broad question but wanted some help narrowing it down.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ....
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
 new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdaptor);
 dataAdaptor.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
 ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you set up all your Command properties for Select, Insert, Update, & Delete? These need to be configured before you can use the SqlDataAdaptor

Also see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx). The SqlCommandBuilder can automatically generate the command properties for you as long as you have your Select command set.